# Python Map in Class functions

Tags: python

Very simple

I have this:

```
for i in self.Abilities:
    i.OnTimer(amount)
```

Can i have something like this instead?

```
map(Ability.OnTimer,self.Abilities,amount)
```

I want to use map with class functions but i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `functools.partial` to provide arguments to a function before calling it:

```
from functools import partial

map(partial(Ability.OnTimer, amount = amount), self.Abilities)
```

But do you really think this would be more readable? And mind that `map` is lazy in Python 3!

Answer (score 6):

You should use `map` to calculate a list of values, not for its side effects.  If you're performing a sequence of actions, it's more readable to use the `for` loop.  People will more easily understand the intent of your code.